# Inquiry Regarding CASA Verification Process for my flutter Application

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-fit

We have used Google Fit API in our Flutter app for collecting user steps data. We have used the "health" package and during the development phase, there was an option to add test accounts and QA the app functionality. After completion of development when we turn the project from testing to production at the Google Cloud console a message pops up that says we have to verify my project because we are using some sensitive scope. We have filled out the verification form and completed the phase 1. Now in phase 2, they recommend verifying our app at the CASA portal and getting a certificate. Our concern is CASA tier 2 process require source code to verify our app and we are little bit confused why should we share our source code to Third party?

Email:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmX0K.png)

Our Scopes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGupT.png)

We aimed to find a verification solution or process that doesn't necessitate sharing our entire source code with a third party while complying with Google's verification requirements. Our expectation was to gather insights, alternative methods, or guidance from the community on how others navigated similar verification hurdles.

Comment: Unless you have an app that is very unique and very hard to duplicate, I would not worry about sharing source code. In the real world, the source code has little value and can be easily reproduced by experienced developers. The real value is the company, employees, products, and support. Additionally, third-party security vendors have processes to protect your intellectual property. They would be out of business faster than I can tweet if they violated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fluid Attacks CLI which is free and open source. This answer has more information.

[CASA Scan - fluidattacks/cli Doesn't seem to do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78083220/casa-scan-fluidattacks-cli-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything/78122529#78122529)