# CASA Scan - fluidattacks/cli Doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: ios, docker, casa

I'm attempting to run a tier 2 CASA scan on an iOS app using fluidattacks/cli, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure it.

The command I'm running is:
`docker run -v $(pwd)/FluidScanArtifacts:/working-dir fluidattacks/cli:arm64 skims scan /working-dir/MyApp/config.yaml`

And my config.yaml is as follows:

```
namespace: MyApp
output:
  file_path: ./Fluid-Attacks-Results.csv
  format: CSV
working_dir: .
language: EN
sast:
  include:
    - .
  exclude:
    - glob(**/Pods/**)
sca:
  include:
    - .
  exclude:
    - glob(**/Pods/**)
```

When it runs I get no errors and it says no vulnerabilities were found, but I'm not sure it's actually scanning anything as the whole process is taking maybe a second and it says Analysis on 0 paths:

```
INFO] Official Documentation: https://docs.fluidattacks.com/tech/scanner/standalone/
[INFO] Namespace: MyApp
[ERROR] Computing commit hash: /src 
[INFO] info HEAD is now at: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[INFO] Startup work dir is: /src
[INFO] Moving work dir to: /src
[INFO] Running SAST analysis on specified paths
[INFO] Performing lines analysis
[INFO] Performing Path Analysis on 0 paths
[INFO] SAST path analysis completed!
[INFO] Performing graph analysis
[INFO] Performing unverifiable paths analysis
[INFO] SAST analysis completed!
[INFO] Analysis finished, writing results
[INFO] An output file has been written: /src/Fluid-Attacks-Results.csv
[INFO] Summary: No vulnerabilities were found in your targets.
```

So something feels wrong here, and I think it may have to do with the working_dir in the config.yaml which is just set to `.`. I can't figure out what this path is relative to. If I set it to anything besides `.` I just get (after setting it to MyApp):

```
 File "/nix/store/ls4wycw226gqlidzliw3p9bzyr9gknx4-skims/core/scan.py", line 277, in main
    os.chdir(ctx.SKIMS_CONFIG.working_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/src/MyApp'

[INFO] Summary: An error occurred while analyzing your targets.
```

And what is `/src`? I actually did a `docker cp` on the src directory from the container after it ran successfully and all it had is my CSV file. I kind of expected all my code to be in there but it wasn't.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: For me, I don't get the CSV file at the end...

Comment: I actually didn't get it either but I was able to find it on the container

Comment: Yes, found it somewhere in the container as well, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect. You need to change `working-dir` to `src`.
In your example, the command would then become:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/FluidScanArtifacts:/src fluidattacks/cli:arm64 skims scan /src/MyApp/config.yaml
```

I wrote a blog post covering the steps after strugging with this which might help: https://mzansibytes.com/2024/03/07/performing-a-sast-for-a-casa-tier-2-self-scan/

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I tried to access your blog post but somehow it is not loading and Chrome gives an error that the page is unresponsive (same in Safari). It seems that some of the images are not loading. Your guide seems super helpful so it would be awesome to be able to read it. Thanks a ton and hopefully you can fix your page! Cheers!

Comment: It's fixed. Sorry, I was testing the Jetpack Boost plugin, but it seems to have issues.